# Component not updating after dispatch gets called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a to-do list react-redux application which I'm trying to get the hang of how redux works. I created a beginners to-do-list application.

The problem I'm having, is the child component, `ToDoList.jsx`, doesn't update when `dispatch` is called from another file, but the `mapStateToProps` *does* get called, and returns the correct info. The component just doesn't rerender.

#### Description of App

There are two components (other than app.js), `AddToList.jsx`, which has a label that mirrors the textfield, and a button that lets you add things to the array of to do lists.

Next, there's a child component called `ToDoList.jsx` which displays the array of, to do items.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/4wxwvp1r00)

App.js

```
...
  <div className="App">
    <Provider store={store}>
          <AddToList />
    </Provider>
  </div>
...
```

AddToList.jsx

```
...
    <>
        <input type="text" value={props.inputText} placeholder="To do item" onChange={props.inputChangeHandler}/>
        <button type="button" onClick={props.addToListHandler}>Add To List</button>
        <ToDoList />
    </>
...



function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        inputText: state.inputText
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        inputChangeHandler: (evt) => {
            const action = {type: 'INPUT_CHANGE', text: evt.target.text};
            dispatch(action);
        },
        addToListHandler: () => {
            const action = {type: 'ADD_TO_LIST'};
            dispatch(action);
        }
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(AddToList);
```

ToDoList.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const ToDoList = (props) => {

    return ( 
        <ul>
            {props.toDoList.map((toDoItem, index) => {
                return <li key={index}>{toDoItem}</li>
            })}
        </ul>
     );
}




function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log(state.toDoList);
    // ******* Gets Called, and logs correct data **********

    return {
        toDoList: state.toDoList
    };
}


export default connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(ToDoList);
```

Comment: Could you also post your reducer? Better yet, could you convert this into a runnable snippet or create a version in codesandbox.io?

Comment: @sampathsris On my phone now, will do it tomorrow, but just to be clear, the reducer is getting called, since in the ToDoList.jsx file, the function of mapStateToProps gets called and it has the correct info.

Comment: What is the shape of the `toDoList` prop in `ToDoList`? Is it an array? Try changing `<li key={index}>` to `<li key={toDoItem}>`. It is possible that the component is not getting updated because you are using array index for key.

Comment: @sampathsris toDoList is an array of strings. I checked the key from I index to toDoItem, but still have the same problem. (Is it illegal to use index as the key?)

Comment: [Index as a key is an anti-pattern](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)

Comment: @sampathsris Interesting! Didn't know that! Thanks!

Comment: @sampathsris Added the codeSandbox. Sorry for the delay. Was just crazy busy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using this piece of code:

```
case "ADD_TO_LIST":
  newState.toDoList.push(state.inputText);
  break;
```

Since you `push` to the `newState.toDoList` array, the reducer returns the same object (but mutated). `connect` will provide the same object for the React component when the state changes. However, React will not update the list, since it is the same object (by reference).

Instead, you could do something like this, that does not mutate the original object:

```
case "ADD_TO_LIST":
  const toDoList = [...state.toDoList, state.inputText];
  newState = {
    ...state,
    toDoList
  };
  break;
```

See the action here: https://codesandbox.io/s/11764qzpj (But notice that there still is a bug! Try editing the input and adding it to the list. I'll leave this as an exercise to you).

---

**Side note:** I also noted that you are creating a `newState` every time the reducer is called. But this is unnecessary and often harmful. If there is no change to the state, you should always return the original `state` object. Otherwise React will think that state has changed and unnecessarily try to re-render components.